# Why np.linalg.eig(L) can't get the right results?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, eigenvector

We all known that the smallest eigenvalue of laplacian matrix is zero, and the eigenvector is `[1 1 ... 1]`, because of the sum of each row is zero.
So for matrix:`[[ 1. -1.  0.][-1.  2. -1.][ 0. -1.  1.]]`

I try `np.linalg.eig(L)`, `np.linalg.eigh(L)`, `scipy.linalg.eig(L)`, but each of them can't get the zero and `[1 1 ... 1]`.

In `np.linalg.eig(L)`:

```
(-3.367702055640532e-17, 0.9999999999999998, 2.999999999999999)
(array([-0.40824829,  0.70710678,  0.57735027]), array([8.16496581e-01, 2.61239546e-16, 5.77350269e-01]), array([-0.40824829, -0.70710678,  0.57735027]))
```

In `np.linalg.eigh(L)`:

```
(9.996582244115599e-17, 1.0, 3.0)
(array([-0.57735027, -0.70710678,  0.40824829]), array([-5.77350269e-01,  7.58447699e-17, -8.16496581e-01]), array([-0.57735027,  0.70710678,  0.40824829]))
```

In `scipy.linalg.eig(L)`:

```
((-3.367702055640532e-17+0j), (0.9999999999999998+0j), (2.999999999999999+0j))
(array([-0.40824829,  0.70710678,  0.57735027]), array([8.16496581e-01, 2.61239546e-16, 5.77350269e-01]), array([-0.40824829, -0.70710678,  0.57735027]))
```

I know the computer representation error, but the eigenvector is far from `[1 ... 1]^T`.

Comment: Note that the returned eigenvectors are normalized to have unit length (see: [numpy.linalg.eig](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html)). Also, due to computations using floating-point arithmetic, you can't get exact zeros, but some small values such as -3.367702055640532e-17 you have obtained.

Comment: I know I can't get exact zeros, but the corresponding eigenvector should be closed to `[1 1 ... 1]`. In `np.linalg.eig(L)`, it is `[-0.40824829, 8.16496581e-01, -0.40824829]`. In `np.linalg.eigh(L)`, it is `[-0.57735027, -5.77350269e-01, -0.57735027]`. In `scipy.linalg.eig(L)`, it is `[-0.40824829, 8.16496581e-01, -0.40824829]`. And I think only `np.linalg.eigh(L)` has right eigenvector. Why the others get wrong eigenvector? And what is difference in this three functions?